# LSTM network returns more than one output

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, stock

I'm learning LSTM networks and the output I'm getting is unexpected.
I have created an LSTM and fed it with two numpy arrays:

- input.shape --> (2158, 2, 1) --> this contains stock's close and volume prices
- output.shape --> (2158, 1, 1) --> this contains the stock's close price of the following day

After I use the model to predict the input, I would expect the prediction shape to be (2158, 1, 1) but it is (2158, 2, 1).

Why is that? How can I change it to predict the target prices?

```
def main():
    training_data=gettrainingdata()
    training_set_scaled=scale(training_data)
    x,y = getxy(training_set_scaled)
    x,y = reshape(x,y)
    model=returnmodel(x, y)
    model=train(model,x,y)
    predicted=predict(model,x)
    

def individual_stock(price_df,vol_df,name):
    return pd.DataFrame({  "Date":price_df["Date"],"Close":price_df[name],"Volume":vol_df[name]   })

def gettrainingdata():
    path= (pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute())
    stock_price_df = pd.read_csv(f"{path}/stock_prices.csv")
    stock_vol_df = pd.read_csv(f"{path}/stock_volume.csv")
    stock_price_df = stock_price_df.sort_values(by = ["Date"])
    stock_vol_df = stock_vol_df.sort_values(by = ["Date"])
    #Concatenates the data of one stock date prices and volume as dictionaries
    price_volume_df = individual_stock(stock_price_df,stock_vol_df,"sp500")
    training_data=price_volume_df.iloc[:,1:3].values
   
    print("""
       
      1)
      returning training data as:
      <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
      shape: (2159, 2)

 _________________________________         
          """)
 #   print(training_data)
  #  print(type(training_data))
   # print(training_data.shape)   
    
    
    return training_data


def scale(training_data):
    sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
    training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(training_data)
    
    print("""
       
      2)
      MixMaxScalar
      returning scaled training data as:
      <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
      shape: (2159, 2)

 _________________________________
          """)
    
#    print(training_set_scaled)
 #   print(type(training_set_scaled))
  #  print(training_set_scaled.shape)
    return training_set_scaled

def getxy(training_set_scaled):
    dim1,dim2=training_set_scaled.shape
    X=[]
    Y=[]
    for i in range(1,(dim1)):
        X.append(training_set_scaled[i-1,:dim2])
        Y.append(training_set_scaled[i,0])
    X,Y=np.asarray(X),np.asarray(Y)
    print("""
       
      3)
      return input and output:
      <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
      (2158, 2) (2158,)

 _________________________________
          """)
#    print(type(X),type(Y))
 #   print((X).shape,(Y).shape)
    return X,Y


def reshape(x,y):
    dimX1,dimX2=x.shape
    x = np.reshape(   x,  (dimX1,dimX2,1)   )
    y = np.reshape(   y,  (y.shape[0],1,1)   )
    print("""
       
      4)
      return 3d arrays:
      <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
     (2158, 2, 1) (2158, 1, 1)

 _________________________________
          """)
 #   print(type(x),type(y))
 #   print((x).shape,(y).shape)
    return x,y

def returnmodel(x,y):
    dimX1,dimX2,dimX3=x.shape
    inputs=keras.layers.Input(shape= (dimX2,dimX3))
    new = keras.layers.LSTM(150,return_sequences=True)(inputs) 
    new=keras.layers.LSTM(150,return_sequences=True)(new) 
    new=keras.layers.LSTM(150,return_sequences=True)(new) 
    outputs=keras.layers.Dense(1,activation="linear")(new)
    model=keras.Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=outputs) 
    model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss="mse")
    print("""
       
      5)
      created LSTM model

 _________________________________
          """)
    model.summary()
    return model

def train(model,x,y):
    model.fit(x,y, epochs=2, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2 )
    print("""
       
      6)
      the model is trained

 _________________________________
          """)
    return model

def predict(model,x):
    predicted=model.predict(x)
    print("""
       
      7)
      the model is making predictions
      returning an array

 _________________________________
          """)
    print(type(predicted))
    print(predicted.shape)
    dim1,dim2,dim3=predicted.shape
    new = []
    for i in range(dim1):
        new.append([predicted[i][0][0],predicted[i][1][0]])
    df=pd.DataFrame(new)
    print(df)
    return predicted



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The final part of my print:

```
      7)
      the model is making predictions
      returning an array
 
 _________________________________
          
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(2158, 2, 1)
             0         1
0     0.068643  0.054690
1     0.066402  0.020197
2     0.068003  0.052936
3     0.073034  0.067877
4     0.075300  0.107198
       ...       ...
2153  0.891596  1.002645
2154  0.901476  1.022127
2155  0.911437  0.985692
2156  0.912426  0.970935
2157  0.916713  0.995224

[2158 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

in the `returnmodel()` function last LSTM layer `return_sequence` parameter set to `False` or completly drop that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Amazing!

Thanks a lot, I changed the returnmodel function and it works:

```
def returnmodel(x,y):
    dimX1,dimX2,dimX3=x.shape
    inputs=keras.layers.Input(shape= (dimX2,dimX3))
    new = keras.layers.LSTM(150,return_sequences=True)(inputs) 
    new=keras.layers.LSTM(150,return_sequences=True)(new) 
    new=keras.layers.LSTM(150,return_sequences=False)(new) 
    outputs=keras.layers.Dense(1,activation="linear")(new)
    model=keras.Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=outputs) 
    model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss="mse")
    print("""
       
      5)
      created LSTM model

 _________________________________
          """)
    model.summary()
    return model
```

Do you have suggestions of what material I can read to better understand how Kera's LSTM model works? I took a Udemy course but it runs through the code too quickly...

Comment: use documentation by [keras](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/) and [tf2](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM) and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/rnn) you will get extensive details on RNN in tf.